In Wpf, how can I modify a DataTemplate during runtime?
I'm writing a plugin that is loaded into an application whose source is not managed by me. Through the API I am able to get the AvalonDock DockingManager for the application. I'd like to add a binding to control the color of the tabs. I know the datatype of the DataContext and can create a Binding to do what I want.
However, I want the rest of the bindings and triggers associated with the original DataTemplate to remain intact. I can get the DataTemplate from the DockingManager, but once applied, they become sealed so I'm guessing I need to clone it, modify the clone and apply the clone.
I tried using XamlWriter.Save() which gets the template, however the Bindings are stripped from it. If I use XamlReader.Parse() on the output, without any modification, the text for the tabs disappears. Looking at the xaml, the TextBlock.Text property is an empty string.
I considered that the application "manually" sets the text, but inspecting the controls using Visual Studio shows that there are bindings before the Write/Read process.
How can modify a template during runtime to add a custom binding when creation of the template is not under my control?

Changing the Template (no matter the Data Template or the Control) is an inherently bad idea. There are no default ways to obtain a clone of a Template. Template decompilation is possible only for the simplest layouts. Similar questions have already been discussed here many times. You need to find some other way to implement your task.

Is changing the template the bad idea or is cloning and modifying the bad idea? For example, would writing my own from scratch and replacing the existing one be acceptable? If not, and manually applying formatting every time a new item appears is considered bad practice as well, what is the correct way to accomplish this?

The main problem is that you cannot be guaranteed to obtain the source code of the template and, as a result, are guaranteed to make changes to it correctly.
If you have the source code of the template, then it is much easier to create a new template based on it than to make changes to an already used template at runtime.

While not exactly a direct answer to my question, the solution I came up with was actually to modify the Style rather than the Template. From the DockingManager I got the LayoutDocumentPaneControl with the Tabs I wanted to change. I got its ItemContainerStyle, made a new one BasedOn the old one and could add Setters as needed which kept everything the same except what I was trying to override specifically.
void OverwriteTabStyle()
{
    MultiBinding binding = CreateTabBinding(); //Create the binding to set the background color based on context
    var dockingManager = _dockingManagerProvider.GetDockingManager(); //Get access to the DockingManager
    var layoutDocumentPaneControl = dockingManager.FindVisualChildren<LayoutDocumentPaneControl>().FirstOrDefault();
    Style oldStyle = layoutDocumentPaneControl.ItemContainerStyle;
    Style newStyle = new Style(typeof(TabItem), oldStyle);
    newStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Panel.BackgroundProperty, binding)); //Only modifies single property while maintaining other Bindings
    newStyle.Seal();
    layoutDocumentPaneControl.ItemContainerStyle = newStyle;
}

